# kde 4.13 and oxygen transparent

Tags: kubuntu, kde, transparency

Hi guys I downloaded and installed Kubuntu 14.04 yesterday and set all options and customization as I want but one of my favourite options is set my widget style to **oxygen-transparent** which make whole desktop environment kde to be have transparent I can do that to kde 4.11 but after installed kubuntu 14.04 which came with kde 4.13 this theme can't work and doesn't make my desktop environment to be transparent

Is oxygen-transparent not compatible anymore with higher kde version???

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/oxygen-transparent?content=127752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it isn't compatible with KDE 4.13. I tried to use it on an Arch install and it does not load the transparency effects. I have looked into their repository and didn't see any recent activity to make widget compatible cu KDE 4.13. Latest commits were from 2013-12-18 02:15 pm

You can check here:

https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/artwork/oxygen-transparent/repository

Comment: thank you I thought in that and only want to see anyone have same problem or just me feel sorry it's great awesome affect in kde